# Kali Linux And Android

Tags: root-access, linux, dual-boot

I like to root and tinker around with old Android devices, be it smartphones and tablets. I want to use root access to install Kali Linux, but I want to know what features this version of Kali Linux has to offer. I'm not expecting much, but the file size is pretty big, so it should be something.

wasn't sure if this can be posted here or on the Unix site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kali is very popular and has pretty much any hacking tool u need. https://www.parrotsec.org is also a Security based linux distro there site has lists of everything they include.

Comment: So is the mobile version of Kali just as good as the proper version? As in terms of tools.

Comment: There is no Kali version of linux. There are tools for android that do similar to kail. but id  say Kali on desktop is still king